# Get all the npm packages containing a keyword

Tags: node.js, npm, keyword

I want to get all the [npm](http://npmjs.com) packages containing the `foo` keyword.

How is that possible using the NPM api? I cannot find any docs regarding that. Is it possible to do it with the `npm` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`npm` package's `search`](https://docs.npmjs.com/api/search) function, like this

```
var npm = require("npm");

npm.load({}, function () {

    npm.commands.search("foo", true, function (err, result) {

        if (err) {
            throw new Error(err);
        }
        console.log(Object.keys(result));

    });

});
```

It returns `355` objects for the `foo` keyword.

The callback function which we pass to the `search` function, will receive an object, with the keys being the package names and values being information about the packages. Quoting the documentation,

> Returns an object where each key is the name of a package, and the value is information about that package along with a 'words' property, which is a space-delimited string of all of the interesting words in that package. The only properties included are those that are searched, which generally include:
>
> - name
> - description
> - maintainers
> - url
> - keywords

**Note:** The second parameter (`true`) passed to the `search` function is to prevent the function from printing the result on stdout. Basically it enables the silent mode.

You can also limit the search by using multiple keywords, by passing an array to the `search` function, like this

```
npm.commands.search(["foo", "bar"], true, function (err, result) {
```

returns only 39 objects.

Comment: I published a new package and it's not indexed. Is it possible to refresh it somehow?

Comment: @IonicăBizău There is one more parameter called `staleness`. I am not sure how to make use of it. Doc says `This is the threshold for stale packages. "Fresh" packages are not refreshed from the registry. This value is measured in seconds.`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of depending on the gigantic `npm` module, I made a tiny module for this exact purpose: [`npm-keyword`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/npm-keyword).